# Can't parse all JSON items

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse this JSON response:

```
[
   "http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce",
   "udp://open.demonii.com:1337/announce",
   "udp://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce",
   "udp://tracker.leechers-paradise.org:6969/announce",
   "udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce"
]
```

With:

```
for item in jdata:
    torrent_tracker = item
    print(torrent_tracker)
magnet = "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:" + hash + "&tr=" + torrent_tracker
```

But it only seems to get each line separately. Is there a way I can get the all of the JSON results in to the `torrent_tracker` var?

A valid torrent tracker for that JSON could be:

`&tr=udp://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce&tr=udp://tracker.leechers-paradise.org:6969/announce&tr=udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce&tr=udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969/announce`

Comment: What is *in* `jdata`? How did you decode the JSON?

Comment: jdata its the pastebin result ,i decoded by ```jdata = self.getURL(trackerUrl, json=True)```  trackerURL being a var

Comment: That doesn't look like a standard API I'm familiar with. Are you perhaps using [SickRage](https://github.com/SiCKRAGETV/SickRage)? If so, that then tells me what the `json=True` flag *does*; in this case it does return a Python object after decoding the response body (SickRage uses `requests` under the hood so we can trust it does this right).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `+=` (in python 3).

`torrent_tracker = torrent_tracker + item` works for any python.

If you'd like a list, above your for loop, put `torrent_tracker = []` and wrap item in `[]` (`torrent_tracker = torrent_tracker + [item]`). For a string, set `torrent_tracker = ''` before the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a `for` loop. You can prepend all strings in a list with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
["&tr=" + s for s in jdata]
```

And you can then join them with `string.join()`.

So, for example, this might work for you:

```
magnet = "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:" + hash + "".join(["&tr=" + s for s in jdata])
```

Although if you're planning on sending these as parameters of a GET you'll probably want to URL encode them first ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `join()` method without loop:

```
 torrent_tracker = '&tr=' + '&tr='.join(jdata)
 magnet = "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:" + hash + torrent_tracker
```